# Create a subsection in SitePages

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sitepages, pages, collapsible-sections

Is there a way to create a subsection in a SharePoint page?

For example, I would like to create a collapsible subsection under Database:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in SharePoint online modern experience.

You cannot add section inside another section. You can only add columns and web parts inside a section.

**Related links**:

1. [Add sections and columns on a SharePoint modern page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-sections-and-columns-on-a-sharepoint-modern-page-fc491eb4-f733-4825-8fe2-e1ed80bd0899)
2. [SharePoint: Collapsible sections on modern pages](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/07/01/sharepoint-collapsible-sections-on-modern-pages/)